# Constructing a quotient ring of multivatiate polynomial ring in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gap

I need to construct the following ring in GAP:

$$F_2(u_1,u_2) / \langle u_1^2=u_2^2=0,u_1u_2=u_2u_1 \rangle $$.

This is what I tried and it didn't work:

```
gap> R:=PolynomialRing(GF(2),["u1","u2"]);AssignGeneratorVariables(R);
GF(2)[u1,u2]
#I  Assigned the global variables [ u1, u2 ]
gap> I:=Ideal(R,[(u1)^2,(u2)^2,u1*u2-u2*u1]);
<two-sided ideal in GF(2)[u1,u2], (3 generators)>
gap> A:=R/I;
Error, List Element: <list>[1] must have an assigned value in
return i[LeadingMonomialPosExtRep( fam, i, orderext )]; called from
func( C[i] ) called from
List( baslte, function ( i )
  return i[LeadingMonomialPosExtRep( fam, i, orderext )];
end ) called from
GBASIS.GroebnerBasis( elms, order ) called from
ReducedGroebnerBasis( GeneratorsOfIdeal( I ), order ) called from
GroebnerBasis( I, ord ) called from
...  at line 9 of *stdin*
you can 'return;' after assigning a value
brk>
```

Does anyone know how to construct this ring in GAP?

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Please use four spaces to indent GAP code, otherwise it is quite unreadable. See how I've edited your question from yesterday for GAP code (and also for the formula).

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor quirk in the code in that ideal generators $0$ are not processed properly. Remove `u1*u2-u2*u1`(which holds anyhow) and everything will work fine.