# The subgroup of $SL_2(F)$ generated by 2 elements in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gap

Edited:How we should find the order of $A$ in $S = SL_2(F)$? (Solved)

$F = GF(2)[x] / \langle x^{63}+x+1 \rangle. $

```
x:=X(GF(2),"x");
pol:=x^63+x+1;
e:=AlgebraicExtension(GF(2),pol);
alpha:=PrimitiveElement(e);
A:=[[alpha^3+One(e),1],[1,0]]*One(e);
B:=[[alpha^5+alpha+One(e),alpha],[1,0]]*One(e);
g:=Group(A,B);
```

Second question: How we should define a group generated by $A, B$ $\in SL_2(F)$? and analysis it (StructureDescription(g), or at least calculate the size of $g$)

Comment: Supposedly is simply $R/I$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652338/constructing-a-quotient-ring-of-multivatiate-polynomial-ring-in-gap, https://bitbucket.org/gap-system/gap/issues/5/quotient-ring-as-a-field.

Comment: hmm, entries of `A` and `B` does not belong to `F` - they are in `R`. Also, why do you need `S` for this question?

Comment: I want some other stuff! For example the subgroup of $S$ generated by $A$ and $B$.

Comment: But `S` is a Lie algebra, not a group. Also, btw, not all entries of `A` in `B` are even in  `R`, because 1 and 0 are integers.

Comment: P.S. I've tried to construct `A` and `B` properly with entries in `F` and then it's still a valid question how to do this to avoid "no-method-found" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There way you describe the input there is some confusion between what `x` is and what the appropriate 1 and 0 are. GAP will distinguish between 1 (as an element of the rational numbers) and the one of `GF(2)`, the one of the polynomial ring, and the one of the quotient ring. You need to create these as different objects.
Also there is no need to construct the Lie algebra.

So my suggestion for building this example would be to use `AlgebraicExtension` to construct the particular field you need. That is:

```
gap> x:=X(GF(2),"x");
x
gap> pol:=x^63+x+1;
x^63+x+Z(2)^0
gap> e:=AlgebraicExtension(GF(2),pol);
<algebra-with-one of dimension 63 over GF(2)>
gap> alpha:=PrimitiveElement(e);
a
```

Now construct the matrices, ensuring all elements lie over the correct field, and you can construct a group:

```
gap> A:=[[alpha^3+One(e),1],[1,0]]*One(e);
[ [ a^3+Z(2)^0, !Z(2)^0 ], [ !Z(2)^0, !0*Z(2) ] ]
gap> B:=[[alpha^5+alpha+One(e),alpha],[1,0]]*One(e);
[ [ a^5+a+Z(2)^0, a ], [ !Z(2)^0, !0*Z(2) ] ]
gap> g:=Group(A,B);
```

Caveat: This being an abstract field, most calculations defer to generic routines, and thus are slow. Furthermore the matrices you give have high order. You might want to experiment with field extensions of smaller degree first.

If you really need this particular case of matrices, probably starting with the minimal polynomial will be the best bet:

```
gap> MinimalPolynomial(e,A);
x_1^2+(a^3+Z(2)^0)*x_1+!Z(2)^0
```

This is irreducible, but the minimal polynomial of $B$ splits:

gap> Factors(MinimalPolynomial(e,B));

```
    [x_1(a^60+a^57+a^56+a^55+a^53+a^52+a^51+a^50+a^49+a^46+a^45+a^40+a^39+a^38+a^34+a^32+a^31+a^29+a^28+a^26+a^24+a^21+a^20+a^12+a^11+a^10+a^9+a^4+a^3),
    x_1(a^60+a^57+a^56+a^55+a^53+a^52+a^51+a^50+a^49+a^46+a^45+a^40+a^39+a^38+a^34+a^32+a^31+a^29+a^28+a^26+a^24+a^21+a^20+a^12+a^11+a^10+a^9+a^5+a^4+a^3+a+Z(2)^0)]
gap> r:=RootsOfPolynomial(MinimalPolynomial(e,B));
```

Thus the order of $B$ is the lcm of the multiplicative orders of the two eigenvalues in $r$. In this case both are primitive elements, that is the order of $B$ will be $2^{63}-1$:

```
gap> mo:=2^63-1;
9223372036854775807
gap> f:=Set(Factors(mo));
[ 7, 73, 127, 337, 92737, 649657 ]
gap> Filtered(f,x->IsOne(r[1]^(mo/x)));
[  ]
gap> Filtered(f,x->IsOne(r[2]^(mo/x)));
[  ]
```

As the minimal polynomial of $A$ is irreducible, it will split over a degree 2 extension, i.e. a field of order $2^{126}-1$. We verify that indeed this must be a multiple of the order of $A$:

```
gap> mo:=2^(2*63)-1;
85070591730234615865843651857942052863
gap> IsOne(A^mo);
true
```

Now we proceed in a standard way, dividing off primes that do not occur in the order:

```
gap> aord:=mo;                         
85070591730234615865843651857942052863
gap> f:=Set(Factors(mo));
[ 3, 7, 19, 43, 73, 127, 337, 5419, 92737, 649657, 77158673929 ]
gap> sel:=Filtered(f,x->aord mod x=0 and IsOne(A^(aord/x)));
[ 7, 73, 127, 337, 92737, 649657 ]
gap> aord:=aord/Product(sel);   
64563604257983430663
gap> IsOne(A^aord);
true
gap> sel:=Filtered(f,x->aord mod x=0 and IsOne(A^(aord/x)));
[ 7 ]
gap> aord:=aord/Product(sel);
9223372036854775809
gap> sel:=Filtered(f,x->aord mod x=0 and IsOne(A^(aord/x)));
[  ]
```

So the order of $A$ is (drumroll...) $9223372036854775809=3^3\cdot 19\cdot 43\cdot 5419\cdot 77158673929$.

Comment: Thank you. One other point is that I'm highly interested to know that what is $g$? i.e. StructureDescription(g); But it seems that GAP cannot handle this command.

Comment: `StructureDescription` (one of the most misleading and misunderstood functions, as it will*only* work for tiny examples) is beyond hopeless to expect it to work here. I doubt that even computing the order of the group with `Size` will work. The determinant of $A$ is 1, the determinant of $B$ is $a$, and the order of $B$ is the order of $A$. So the group is a semidirect product of the cyclic group $\langle A\rangle$ (probably subgroup of a Singer cycle) with the multiplicative group of the field.